# Minimizing inversions in an array with a single swap

Tags: algorithms, optimization, correctness-proof, permutations

This was asked in the (very) recently concluded [Hackerrank Worldcup](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/worldcupsemifinals/challenges/lauren-and-inversions). Paraphrased:

> Given a permutation $a$ of integers from $1$ to $N$, how can I
>   minimize the number of inversions by a single swap of any two
>   integers?
>
> An inversion is a pair of indices $(i, j)$ such that $i < j$ but 
>   $a[i] > a[j]$.

I think that this can be achieved by swapping the numbers which have been shifted the most from their position. That is:

If $n_{inv}(a)$ is the number of inversions in a permutation $a$, and $swap_a(i, j)$ is the permutation obtained by swapping the integers at $i$, $j$, then:

$$
\underset{i, j}{argmin} \{n_{inv}(swap_a(i, j))\} = 
\underset{i}{argmax} (a[i] -i), \underset{j}{argmin} (a[j] -  j)
$$

In pseudo-code:

```
leftmost = [-1, -1]        # The first value is the displacement
rightmost = [1, -1]        # The second the index where it occurred
for i in 1..n
    d = N[i] - i           # N being the array of numbers
    if d > leftmost[0]
        leftmost[0] = d
        leftmost[1] = i
    else if d < rightmost[0]
        rightmost[0] = d
        rightmost[1] = i
return leftmost[1], rightmost[1]
```

---

The thing is, I have no idea *why* this is correct, or even if it is. How can I prove that this works?
Or determine the conditions for which it will work?

---

I have been struggling to understand how I reached this idea and feel that proving it would help me.

To be clear, I am not looking for a solution to the minimizing inversions problem, but only a way to prove that the solution I came up with is correct or incorrect.

Comment: It didn't work for some of the test cases, ergo it is incorrect.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the coding problem itself has some extra conditions (like lexicographically earlier set of indices being preferred, the output being a given string if you cannot decrease the number of inversions, etc.). Neither of us can be sure that these conditions aren't the reason for the failure in those test cases (that's to say - error in implementation vs error in algorithm).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus for example, the method above will always return a set of valid indices, and it might be that for some cases, swapping these indices keeps the number of inversions same (only case I can think of when this can happen is when the integers are sorted, but if there is another case...).

Comment: Then implement the extra conditions!

Comment: @Raphael I did, to the best I could. But, as I said, I don't know if I'm missing an edge case.

Comment: @Raphael I added [tag:sorting] because inversions usually pop in merge-sort (and commonly suggested ways of finding inversions or counting them involve merge-sort).

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bad place for "check my algorithm" type of questions. Please try to formulate an argument for why your solution should be correct.

Comment: @Raphael "try to formulate an argument" ... that is precisely what I am trying to do. "How can I formally prove that this works, or disprove if it doesn't?"

Comment: @Raphael close it as off-topic if you will, then.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: In other words, Raphael is right.  I suggest you try the obvious things yourself, and then edit the question to show what you've tried.  This is not the right place for "check whether my answer is correct" questions.  The obvious things to try are: try implementing a reference solution, then try an automated search for a counterexample (e.g., by generating one million random test cases, and compare what your solution gives to the reference solution to see if your solution gives the correct answer in all cases); (cont.)

Comment: try to prove your solution correct, or prove it correct for some special cases (e.g., where all the elements are distinct, or where the array has at most 1 inversion, or where the array has at most 5 elements, etc.).

Comment: @D.W. I'll try automating some tests, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let's calculate the difference in number of inversions given that you swap $a_i$ and $a_j$. We can assume that $i < j$. There are three kinds of pairs of indices whose status (being inversions or not) could change as a result of the swap: $(i,j)$ and, for $i < k < j$, $(i,k)$ and $(k,j)$. We can distinguish two cases: $a_i < a_j$ and $a_i > a_j$.

If $a_i < a_j$ then the pair $(i,j)$ becomes an inversion, and for every $i < k < j$, there are three possible cases:

1. $a_k < a_i < a_j$: number of inversions stays the same.
2. $a_i < a_j < a_k$: number of inversions stays the same.
3. $a_i < a_k < a_j$: number of inversions increases by 2.

This is clearly not a good idea if you can avoid it. If you must (when the permutation is monotone increasing), it's best to switch a pair $a_i,a_{i+1}$.

In contrast, if $a_j < a_i$ then the number of inversions decreases by one plus twice the number of indices $i < k < j$ such that $a_j < a_k < a_i$. As a consequence, if the permutation is not monotone increasing, your goal is to choose a pair $(i,j)$ such that $a_j < a_i$ and the number of indices $i < k < j$ satisfying $a_j < a_k < a_i$ is maximal. You take it from here.